# How to crop out the annotation box and everything within it?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, python-imaging-library, opencv

After running yolov8, the algorithm annotated the following picture: [Density-Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMcyt.jpg)

My goal is to crop out a large number of these pictures to use in the further analysis. So, I want everything within the bounding box saved, and everything else outside of it removed.

I tried using torch, numpy, cv2, and PIL but haven't been successful.

```
import torch
import torchvision
from PIL import Image

# Load the image
image = Image.open("path to .jpg")

# Define the model and download the pre-trained weights
model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True, weights=None)

# Set the model to evaluation mode
model.eval()

# Transform the image to a tensor
transform = torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()
image_tensor = transform(image)

# Make predictions on the image using the model
predictions = model([image_tensor])

# Extract the bounding boxes and object labels from the predictions
boxes = predictions[0]['boxes'].tolist()
labels = predictions[0]['labels'].tolist()

# Crop the image for each object detected
for i in range(len(boxes)):
    bbox = tuple(boxes[i])
    object_label = labels[i]
    object_image = image.crop(bbox)
    object_image.save(f"image_save.jpg")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If it's just the cropping that isn't working you can make a simpler example without all the torch stuff, then there'll be more folk who will be able to help, see [mcve]. Maybe share the bounding box coordinates you are using and the corresponding image and the minimal code to crop. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, sorry for the confusion, but that's what I'm trying to figure out. Is there a way of doing this without using bounding box coordinates.

Comment: Try printing `bbox` on the line before `image.crop()` and [edit] the output into your question.

Answer (score 1):

The image is just an nd-array, so just use array indexing to perform the cropping operation you desire.

For example I assume your bounding boxes are of the form `[xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax]`.

```
for i in range(len(boxes)):
    object_label = labels[i]
    object_image = image_tensor
    crop = object_image[:,ymin:ymax,xmin:xmax]

    # permute color dimension last
    crop = crop.permute(1,2,0)

    # convert from tensor to numpy array
    crop = crop.data.numpy()
    
    # swap from RGB to BGR (per opencv convention)
    crop = crop[:,:,::-1]

    # save
    cv2.imwrite("output_image.jpg",crop)
```

I'm sure you could accomplish this working directly with the PIL image objects as well but more generally in response to your comment: NO, you cannot crop an image without providing the coordinates of the cropping bounding box.